# Polymer makes F12 tools in IE11 and Edge extremely slow

Tags: polymer-2.x

I have a very simple page that includes webcomponents-lite.js polyfill v1.1.1 and polymer.html v2.6.0. I open the page, served through polymer serve, in IE11 or Edge. When I open F12 tools, it takes up to several minutes until the tools are ready and responsive. This makes it extremely frustrating to debug IE compatibility issues. What is the cause? Can it be improved?

The same problem occurs in earlier versions of webcomponentsjs and polymer. Including webcomponentsjs alone does not seem to have the effect.

Comment: not only IE but also chrome. Few months ago it was much more worse but google did some improvements. Well I don't think there is anything you can do. It's caused by many many and many css mixins that are defined in paper styles and other elements. Maybe I am wrong, but I tried few solutions by myself and everything was unsucessfull